# Xamarin and Shared Project - Can't display an Image

Tags: image, xaml, xamarin, cross-platform

my solution is structured like this:

```
- MyApp.Shared (Shared Project)
  |- myPage.xaml
- MyApp.Android (Android Project)
  |- Resources
     |- drawable
        |- img-1.png (BuildAction: AndroidResource, Do not Copy)
- MyApp.iOS (iOS Project)
  |- Resources
     |- img-1.png (BuildAction: BundleResource, Do Not Copy)
```

And in my xaml page (in the shared project) i've this simple piece of code:

```
<Image Aspect="AspectFit" Source="img-1.png">
```

Why i can't see image (in the droid and ios app)

I followed the Xamarin [Tutorial](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/images/)

Comment: What is your Image wrapped in?

Comment: is in a stacklayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dashes in the name of the resource brokes the regeneration of `Resource.Designer.cs` 
The name given was `img-1.png`: I renamed it to `img1.png` and it works